# Is it safe to use user input in element attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it safe to store a potential harmful user input this way:

```
var rootDiv = document.createElement("div");
rootDiv.setAttribute("data-userid", userId);
```

`userId` comes from the server.

**Update**
Sorry I think I was not clear a bit.. `userId` comes from the server but another user has sent it previously.

**Update 2**
And but harmful, I mean for the user, like a malicious script.

Comment: if you claim that userID comes from the server, then presumably your server can make sure it's not harmful?

Comment: @ADyson another user first send the data to the server. I think server is not responsible for taking care of it?

Comment: Well if another user is sending that to your server beforehand, then your server should ensure it's not harmful before it does _anything_ with it - either processing it, storing it or putting it into another page. You should _always_ verify any incoming data to your server. So it should have been verified a long time before you use it in your JavaScript. Equally, if this value is then sent back to your server from this new page, you should verify it again in case it's been tampered with (again, just like you should verify all data coming to the server from any request from a client)

Comment: And by harmful - that could be meant in any sense, depending where the value is to be used, e.g. harmful to your database (invalid values that would cause an insert/update to fail, or containing SQL injection attempts), harmful to a page (containing script injection or invalid markup, for instance), or harmful to your file system if the value interacts with that. The list is endless depending on your application architecture.

Comment: @ADyson I mean harmful to the page and user

Comment: Ok, well that's fine but as everyone has said. This code _on its own_ is not intrinsically harmful. It's the content of userID that matters. And the place where you check that is on your server, before you display it here. No matter that the value came from somewhere else originally. In fact that's even more reason to verify it before using it, than if the ID was a number generated by your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing about that code is unsafe.

Any risk will come from how you populate the `userId` variable in the first place or what you do with the data later you read `data-userid`.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear at first. userId is of another user's input that came from the server

Comment: @Blendester — It still depends how you are taking the user input, processing it on the server, and outputting it into the JavaScript.

Comment: I still feel a bit guilty for not asking properly what's in my mind. originally my concern is that a user send to the server a malicious script in `FirstName` for example. and I send it to another user and store it in a data attribute without validating it client-side. for a div I do this for example: `var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes your code is fine**, as long as it stays client side. The user can change whatever they want, all changes are only at their side, no-one else will see it as long as you validate it properly. If the Javascript then breaks or gets messed up, then that's too bad for them as only they will experience it.

As long as you don't use that same information serverside, you are absolutely fine. Even if you implement checks for this, they can alter it anyway, as it is clientside. They can destroy a lot more, a lot easier they just this (which is why you always check serverside).
If the value should be an ID, the server should've already checked if it is an ID before even saving it into the DB.

**Edit after your edit**: The fact that this data comes from your server doesnt matter at all, assuming you've already made sure that this data is safe (which it should, as it has already been serverside).

Comment: Sorry I was not clear at first. `userId` is of another user's input that came from the server

Comment: Editted my answer

Comment: "Yes your code is fine, as long as it stays client side. The user can change whatever they want, all changes are only at their side, no-one else will see it." — That isn't true. You can have entirely client side XSS attacks.

Comment: But in just a single data-attribute? but, changed it a tiny bit

Comment: @Martijn — As I said in my answer, the data attribute part is fine. It's the setting of the `userId` variable that could introduce risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm. Well if it is in frontend, anyway not in your hands to safe guard it. Better you have server side validation while processing further requests based on user-id.

in short, check on server that you receiving the same id or not while processing requests.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear at first. userId is of another user's input that came from the server

Comment: @Blendester Will be the same answer. Check on server side that, if it really valid or not while processing it. You shouldn't  trust your browser/user.